# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Recently, I have started  playing with angular 2. It's awesome so far. So, i have started a demo personal project for the sake of learning using `angular-cli`.

With the basic routing setup, I now want to navigate to some routes from header, but since my header is a parent to the `router-outlet`, I receive this error.

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-header></app-header> // Trying to navigate from this component
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**header.component.html**

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/signin']">Sign in</a>
```

Now I understand partially I guess that since that component is a wrapper around `router-outlet` it would not be possible this way to access `router`. So, is there a possibility to access navigation from outside for a scenario like this?

I would be really happy to add any more information if needed. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

1- My `package.json` already has the stable `@angular/router 3.3.1` version.
2- In my main `app` module, I have imported the `routing-module`. Please see below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule  } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from  './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/components/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    LayoutModule,
    UsersModule,
    AppRoutingModule  --> This is the routing module. 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './users/signin/signin.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/components/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The route I am trying to access is delegated from another `module` that is the `UsersModule`

**user-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';

const usersRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signin',  component: SigninComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(usersRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

While I am trying to navigate from a component that is part of the `Layout` module, but has no notion of the router module. Is that what is causing the error.

**Layout.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  exports: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule{}
```

I am trying to navigate from the `HeaderComponent`. I would be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Import RouteModule at root of your app, and update the npm package latest stable version

Comment: Yeah I have the latest stable version.

Comment: Did you also add the `RouterModule` to `imports: []` of all modules where you use `routerLink` or `<router-outlet>`

Comment: @Umair module ordering is important in imports, move `AppRoutingModule` before `LayoutModule`

Comment: @harshes53 I don't think that's true.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That seemed to have solved the issue. But I am sort of confused here. Do we need to add RouterModule to every component module that would need to consume it?

Comment: Exactly. If you use components, directives, or pipes of a module, it needs to be added to imports.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks. Maybe you should add your answer, because the solution you provided was the correct one.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Also, one more thing, in Layout.module.ts would we have to add components to both exports and declarations? What's the difference?

Answer (score 598, accepted):

You need to add `RouterModule` to `imports` of every `@NgModule()` where components use any component or directive from (in this case `routerLink` and `<router-outlet>`.

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
   declarations:[YourComponents],
   imports:[RouterModule]
```

`declarations: []` is to make components, directives, pipes, known inside the current module.

`exports: []` is to make components, directives, pipes, available to importing modules. What is added to `declarations` only is private to the module. `exports` makes them public.

See also https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#usage-notes

Comment: @Gunter is it ok to import RouterModule multiple times ? For example if I want to use routerLink in a childModule, I need to import RouterModule into the child module whereas it has already been imported by the root app Module...

Comment: Yes, it will only included once into the build output.

Comment: Ok but I think we need to take care to call the method `forRoot` only once, the children modules should only import RouterModule without calling the forRoot method

Comment: I think it depends what `forRoot` does. When egistering providers with `forRoot` multiple times, the result is the same as if done only once. If you do other things this might not be different.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! In my case the app worked, but the tests failed. The solution was to import RouterTestingModule in tests, for each component that uses routerLink.

Comment: what about the case where a component is dynamically injected?

Comment: @albanx Can you provide a StackBlitz example?

Comment: this works for `standalone` in Angular 17 as well

Answer (score 38):

You are missing either the inclusion of the route package, or including the router module in your main app module.

Make sure your package.json has this:

```
"@angular/router": "^3.3.1"
```

Then in your app.module import the router and configure the routes:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
            {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
        ])
    ],
```

**Update**:

Move the AppRoutingModule to be first in the imports:

```
imports: [
    AppRoutingModule.
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(), // What is this?
    LayoutModule,
    UsersModule
  ],
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue. Can you please check my update?

Comment: @Ben -- "forRoot()" means you're calling a method defined on an imported module that runs configuration or setup for the module. You can also define a method like "forChild()" in a custom module and call it, if you wanted. This method is used for tasks such as setting up a provider for a service. It's also how you get a Singleton Service in Angular. See https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Making AppRoutingModule to be the first in the import solves the problem

Comment: Thanks man moving the RouterModule before FormsModule solves the problem for me

Answer (score 18):

I'll add another case where I was getting the same error but just being a dummy. I had added `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` without yet adding `routerLinkActive="active"`.

My incorrect code was

```
<a class="nav-link active" routerLink="/dashboard" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Home
</a>
```

when it should have been

```
<a class="nav-link active" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Home
</a>
```

Without having `routerLinkActive`, you can't have `routerLinkActiveOptions`.

Answer (score 17):

You need to import RouterModule in your main module.ts file

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule],
 )}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was getting this error, even though I have exported RouterModule from app-routing.module and imported app-routingModule in Root module(app module).

Then I identified, I've imported component in Routing Module only.

**Declaring the component in my Root module(App Module) solves the problem.**

```
declarations: [
AppComponent,
NavBarComponent,
HomeComponent,
LoginComponent],
```

Comment: This was my issue, but I did not realize it when I read your response. Is it possible to make it more clear that the app.module.ts needs to add the components where you want to include the link in the declarations portion of the @NgModule

Answer (score 14):

Just add `RouterModule` like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SidebarItemComponent } from './sidebar-item/sidebar-item.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SidebarItemComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ], 
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

Answer (score 9):

When nothing else works when it should work, restart ng serve. It's sad to find this kind of bugs.

Comment: Can conform there is a bug.  I just kept deleting the content of the dist folder and rebuilding.  Finally it worked.  Try adding a link to every component in app.component.ts.  If that dosn't work your only option is prayer and fasting.

Comment: Yes restarting ng server was what fixed it for me. After making sure I had  RouterModule imported in the module.Thank you @Tudor

Answer (score 7):

I am running tests for my Angular app and encountered error `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'` as well.

I thought it might be useful to show my Angular dependencies:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
```

The issue was in my `spec` file. I compared to another similar component `spec` file and found that I was missing `RouterTestingModule` in `imports`, e.g.

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [...]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

This problem is because you did not import the module

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
```

And you must declare this modulce in the import section

```
   imports:[RouterModule]
```

Answer (score 4):

Old question, and this doesn't appear to be the OP's issue, but I ended up here when searching for the same "Cannot bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property..." message. I thought I'd share what ended up being my issue in case someone else does the same.

After verifying that RouterModule was included in my AppRoutingModule and routes were all set up correctly to no avail, I finally noticed the very subtle issue: Instead of "`[routerLink]`", I had "`[routerlink]`" with a lower case 'l'.

Funny how your brain can overlook something staring you in the face sometimes.

Comment: i had the same issue, i was starting to question the whole existence of angular, until i saw this one :))

Comment: This man deserves a raise. What a luck I scrolled enough to find this. Thank you stranger!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `RouterMoudle` into `imports` sections of the module containing the `Header` component

Answer (score 3):

I had a standalone component where
`<a [routerLink]="['/details', housingLocation.id]">Learn More</a>`
marked error on `[routerLink]`.

The **answer** was to include

```
import { RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
```

and add the two in the imports of the component
  `imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink, RouterOutlet]`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just need to import my newly created component to **RouterModule**

```
{path: 'newPath', component: newComponent}
```

Then in your `app.module` import the router and configure the routes:

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

```
imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
            {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
            {path: 'newPath', component: newComponent}
        ])
    ],
```

Hope this helps to some one !!!

Answer (score 2):

Just found similar problem in a student's example. After spending 2 hours on checking everything suggested here and in a few similar topics, found that the error was routerlink instead of routerLink.

Seems easy to spot these 'one letter typos', but not in places where you've never saw them before.

Answer (score 1):

I totally chose another way for this method.

app.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {}

    routerComment() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/marketing/social/comment');
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="routerComment()">Router Link </button>
```

Comment: I don't think that's recommended - you will end up with a million click handlers for something that can be automatically handled by Angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

In the current component's module import **RouterModule**.

Like:-

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
   declarations:[YourComponents],
   imports:[RouterModule]
```

...

It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.

What I was doing wrong was I have imported the `RouterModule` in my `AuthModule` as below, but still routing was not working.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

SOLUTION:

Add your `AuthModule` to your main `AppModule` as below:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule // + ADD THIS
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```