# Not Working routerLink on Angular Project even import routerLink type script file as well

Tags: javascript, angular

I need use routerLink on my employee.component.html file like this

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mx-2" routerLink="employee/{{emp.id}}">View Data</button>
</td>
```

and my Route in app.module.ts is

```
{path: 'employee/:id', component:EmployeeByIdComponent}
```

and I have import routerLink on employee.component.ts file as well

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/data.service';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router'; //routerLink


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})



export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  employee:any;

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployeesData();
  }

  getEmployeesData() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
      this.employee = res;
    });
    
  }
}
```

but I got following error message on the IDE
`Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.ngtsc(-998002) employees.component.ts(10, 21): Error occurs in the template of component EmployeesComponent.`

how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure `RouterModule` is imported in your NgModule imports array, [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052263/6519224](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052263/6519224)

Answer (score 0):

To use `RouterLink` in your button you must use `[]`

Like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mx-2" 
    [routerLink]="['employee/'+emp.id]">View Data
</button>
```

*Updated

Comment: existing same error here and url show following `http://localhost:4200/employee/{{emp.id}}`

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: okay now work but in my vs code ide displaying same error message

Comment: What error message ?

Comment: same one like earlier

Comment: May i suggest you this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427405/navigate-to-another-page-with-a-button-in-angular-2